# Is there a way to change the logic options based on which filter is selected for a data?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

| Filter_Type | Filter | Number of Cows |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Country | USA | 4 |
| City | Stuttgart | 2 |
| City | Cheyenne | 5 |
| Country | GER | 100 |
| City | Cheyenne | 7 |
| Country | USA | 1 |

Hello, I would like to know how to do the following in PBI:

When I filter the data by Country, the logic for [Number of Cows] will be displayed as [sum]
But when I filter the data by City the logic for [Number of Cows] will be count

Is there a way to do this without creating a new column?
Thank you!

The easiest way I found how to do this was to create a duplicate column in PBI with the different logic. I would like to learn how to condense this information.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, try this as a Measure:

```
MyMeasure = 
  IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Filter_Type]) = "City",
    // do your count here
    COUNT('Table'[Number of Cows])
    ,
    // do your sum here
    SUM('Table'[Number of Cows])
  )
```